# Does Doctrine's createQueryBuilder bypass the Entities getter methods?

Tags: doctrine-orm, twig, symfony

I'm very new to Symfony coming from a Kohana background and am having a rough time getting used to Doctrine.

Currently I have a product table which I am inner joining some other tables using the createQueryBuilder and need add some extra logic in the getter method for the product Entity. However it would seem that the getter methods aren't even being used. Here is some snippets of my code :

```
//From AppBundle\Controller\ProductController

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
$products = $repository->findWithLimitNew(24);

//From AppBundle\Repositories\ProductRepository
public function findWithLimitNew($limit=1)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select( 'p.name', 'p.id', 'p.slug', 'pc.name AS catname' )
        ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Product', 'p')
        ->innerJoin(
            'AppBundle\Entity\ProductAttributes',
            'pa',
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
            'p.id = pa.productId'
        )
        ->innerJoin(
            'AppBundle\Entity\ProductCategories',
            'pc',
            \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
            'pa.value = pc.id'
        )
        ->where('pa.type = 1')
        ->where('pa.default = 1')
        ->setMaxResults($limit);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

// From AppBundle\Entity\Product
/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    #return $this->name; //<--Commenting this out for now
    return 'Some stupid string';
}

// From index.twig.html
{% for product in products %}
<h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Now as you can see I have the getter method getName() returning a string, but when the view is rendered I get the product name, not the string I'm returning. What gives?

Comment: As you suspected, when hydrating an entity (i.e. retrieving from the database), Doctrine 2 uses reflection to set the entity properties directly.  All methods (including the constructor) are ignored.  And DQL is not SQL.  I'm surprised your query is returning anything at all.

Comment: @Cerad My query comes from a Doctrine website and the query works fine. Of course I modified with my table names.

Comment: Is your "name" field inside AppBundle\Entity\Product marked as pubic? If that's the case it might be because twig sees that the property is pubic and doesn't bother into calling the getter. Try making it private and leaving the getter as public

Answer (score 0):

@Cerad has a point. At first glance your query looks like DQL not QB. However now I realize your code is correct, you can simplify your QueryBuilder (QB) code quite a bit:

```
$qb->select( 'p' )
  ->from('AppBundle:Product', 'p')
  ->innerJoin(
        'AppBundle:ProductAttributes',
        'pa',
        'WITH',
        'p.id = pa.productId'
  )
  ->innerJoin(
        'AppBundle:ProductCategories',
        'pc',
        'WITH',
        'pa.value = pc.id'
  )
  ->where('pa.type = 1')
  ->andWhere('pa.default = 1')
  ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

Notice I use a "andWhere", but your original had a additional "where". I'm surprised that works and didn't throw and error.

Also, I think the main problem is that you just need to understand the returned results. Then in your twig, you don't call the attribute, but instead call the getter like so:

```
// From index.twig.html
{% for product in products %}
    <h1>{{ product.getName }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Can you try these changes? I think calling the getter in the Twig template is the problem.

This might not work. Let us know if it doesn't.

Comment: If the relations are all mapped then innerJoin('p.attributes','pa') is all that is needed.  No need to spell out the with stuff nor to specify the product attribute class.

Comment: I see what you are saying @Cerad and I completely agree with your comments (and thus the upvote). The op is new to Symfony, and I'm just presuming his query works the way it is. Only trying to help get this problem solved. Once he's familiar with the 'easier' way to do it, he can change his design.

Comment: @AlvinBunk when I tried changing to {{product.getName}} and even added the parenthesis to the function I got the dreaded array to string conversion error. From my understanding product.name is actually supposed to be calling the getter getName() but in the case of this type of querying as Cerad was saying, it's hydrating the results directly into an array and not using the getters.

Comment: Because of requirements handed down to me, the product images table doesn't include the path to the images, only the image names. The images come from crawled sites and the requirement is to keep them in different directories based on where they were crawled from. Therefore a simple relationship isn't possible because I need to check where the images were crawled from and construct a path for them and then append the image name. Seems impossible to do with Doctrine. Love ORM's but they can be too restrictive. That's why I loved Kohana so much, it was looser with it's database objects.

Comment: Actually pogeybait, can you do a dump(product.getName) in your Twig in the DEV environment, and post the results. I want to see what it looks like. I'm just now understanding what's being returned. Thanks!

Comment: @AlvinBunk , not much better. I got this error: "Key "getName" for array with keys "name, id, slug, catname" does not exist in product/index.html.twig at line 20" with line 20 being "<h1>{{dump(product.getName)}}</h1>" . Changing line 20 to "<h1>{{dump(product.getName())}}</h1>" returns the error "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in product/index.html.twig at line 20."

Comment: Ah, then try `<h1>{{dump(product.name)}}</h1>` instead and see what that shows.

Comment: It created a javascript that if I tried to paste here in a comment, would go over my character limit by 5000